# set XMPP priority of the jabber client in pidgin

Tags: pidgin, messaging, altlinux, xmpp, jabber

I'm using *pidgin* Jabber client ([pidgin-2.13.0-alt6](https://packages.altlinux.org/en/sisyphus/srpms/pidgin) on ALT Sisyphus), and I'd like [to set XMPP priority](https://superuser.com/a/1137749/65570) in pidgin.

The reason:

I'm also connecting to my Jabber account with another client from mobile smartphone (*aTalk*), and I'd like to set XMPP priority in pidgin, so that whenever I'm at my computer (where pidgin is running), it is [selected as the one which receives the messages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163698/4319) people send to me, and whenever I'm away, the mobile client receives them (because there is more chance I'll see them on the mobile when I'm away).

Where do I set XMPP priority in pidgin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting XMPP priority of your jabber client in pidgin is not going to be implemented in the main pidgin program/purple library, but this feature is added by a plugin in "Purple Plugin Pack". (https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/1345, https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/15460)

To use the mentioned plugin from "Purple Plugin Pack" on ALT Sisyphus and the priority for your jabber client,

- install [`purple-plugin_pack` package](https://packages.altlinux.org/en/sisyphus/srpms/purple-plugin_pack) (`apt-get install purple-plugin_pack`);
- enable it in "Tools > Plugins" menu in pidgin;
- set the values in the range (-128..127) in "Accounts > *your accont* > Edit Account > Advanced > Available/Away Priority"; negative values mean that this client won't receive a message unless the message is explicitly sent to this resource.